# Npgsql Intermittent Connection Timeout Possible Causes

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, npgsql

I am using **npgsql 7.0.4** in a **.net v6** app to execute stored procedures in an **AWS Redshift** cluster and am getting intermittent but regular connection timeouts - this timeout is the one which is defaulted to 15 seconds.

It occurs on about 1% of the calls to the proc and I am looking into what the possible underlying causes might be as the inner exception returned is the standard "System.TimeoutException: Timeout during reading attempt".

I have turned on verbose logging and have captured the trace for one of the instances where it has happened:-

```
[2023-11-03 00:25:06.749203 +00:00 1-65443de2-2239e7486dd5a15b308838fc VRB] Attempting to connect to "host:5439"
[2023-11-03 00:25:06.756942 +00:00 1-65443de2-2239e7486dd5a15b308838fc VRB] SSL negotiation successful
[2023-11-03 00:25:06.756966 +00:00 1-65443de2-2239e7486dd5a15b308838fc VRB] Socket connected to "host":5439
[2023-11-03 00:25:21.752520 +00:00 1-65443de2-2239e7486dd5a15b308838fc VRB] Breaking connection
```

For comparison, this is a trace from when it works normally:-

```
[2023-11-03 07:51:18.539383 +00:00 1-6544a676-1da16696002d39652848e4c4 VRB] Attempting to connect to "host:5439"
[2023-11-03 07:51:18.544360 +00:00 1-6544a676-1da16696002d39652848e4c4 VRB] SSL negotiation successful
[2023-11-03 07:51:18.544390 +00:00 1-6544a676-1da16696002d39652848e4c4 VRB] Socket connected to "host":5439
[2023-11-03 07:51:18.822990 +00:00 1-6544a676-1da16696002d39652848e4c4 DBG] Opened physical connection to "host":5439/"db" (in 283ms)
```

When it works, it only takes milliseconds to progress from "socket connected" to "opened physical connection" - when it fails, you can see the 15 second timeout come into play after "socket connected". I also have a retry policy for this exception, but the second attempt also fails at 15 seconds in exactly the same way.

I am looking through the corresponding redshift log tables/views to see what might be happening server-side, but have not found anything yet.

I am assuming that the issue is **not** network related as it completes the socket connected and ssl negotiation steps successfully, so I have downloaded the Npgsql code and looked into the NpgsqlConnector class to see what happens at that point - I don't fully understand the code, but it looks like there are a number of operations that use that connection timeout e.g. conn.Authenticate, DataSource.Bootstrap.

**Has anyone experienced this kind of issue or know what the usual suspects are when connection timeouts like this occur?**

I originally thought it would be network related, but the logs disprove that theory. Also, I am not sure if it could be as simple as the cluster is being overloaded as the operation normally takes of the order of milliseconds whereas when it times out, it's had 2 tries at 15 seconds each.

I am still investigating the redshift side and I will probably try increasing the timeout from 15s, but at the moment I am still in the dark and would greatly appreciate it if anyone had any advice or previous experience to offer :)

Comment: Have you checked the number of active connections at the time when the timeout occurs?

Comment: I did check on the redshift side and that was ok - the max connection count during the time period i was investigating was about 100 connections, whereas the limit for this cluster is 2000. 

I couldn't figure out how to get connection metrics working in npgsql, I think maybe they are broken until the next version when the whole way of recording metrics is being replaced

Comment: I was taking a look here, maybe this topic can help you 
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1105

Comment: Have you checked that the MTU is 1500 or less?  This doesn’t seem to match your experience exactly but an incorrect MTU can cause a connection to hang and then possibly time out.

Comment: hi vdschuck, i read through the topic and the one it links to, but i think it might be a different issue - it seemed to be network related as the inner exception mentioned a failure of the remote party to respond and the bug in the linked report was related to command timeout and was fixed in v3. but yeah this is the problem i have found in researching this issue, there are soooo many different types of timeouts and causes and it takes ages to find any info on a specific one :(

Comment: hi bill, i'm investigating the mtu now - did you mean the mtu on the redshift side or on the app side? (the app is running in ecs fargate so i'm not sure if i will be able to find out as it is a serverless aws service)